# Building Angular2 app on top of a platform

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-compiler

I'm looking for documentation/guides/any information about the Angular2 compiler. What I'm interested in doing is using Angular2 on top of a different framework (having the components templates translate to the platform code and not regular HTML).

From all that I've seen on Angular2 it should be possible and that's how Angular2 is built on top of ReactNative and NativeScript.

The Angular2 site doesn't have any documentation about this. The closest thing they have is the `@angular/compiler` API - no extra information on that subject.

Anyone know where to start learning/researching this kind of thing?

Comment: I have no suggestions... but isn't that what `NativeScript` does (transpile)? Maybe some clues there? https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular

Comment: @WillTower sorry to say that to complex to understand what they did there without proper documentation